# Laravel: can't retrieve GET data using Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

The following code is not working as I expected:

```
public function cargar_atracciones(Request $request, $id){
  if($request->ajax()){
    $locales = Local::find($id);
    $attractions = Attraction::take($request->get('num'))->where('local_id', $id)->where('estado', 1)->get();

    $atracciones = Attraction::where('estado', 1)->where('local_id', $id)->get();
    $contador = count($atracciones);
    if($contador > $request->get('num')){$var = true;}else{$var = false;} //should be set to false when
// there are no more attractions to show (requested attractions >= total number of attractions in DB)

    return response()->json(['attractions' => $attractions, 'locales' => $locales, 'var' => $var]);
  }
```

This code is from my controller file, it's supposed to get 'num' from a request ("load more" button), pull attractions from DB and send data back to script so it can draw them on http.

'var' is used to set CSS display property of the "load more" button to "none" when there are no attractions left to draw in DB.

Problem is 'var' always returns true, whether the passed 'num' is greater than the total number of attractions in DB or not.

I've checked it many times and could not figure it out.

Could anyone shed some light on why it's behaving this way?

EDIT:

The comparison doesn't work as expected because of `$request->get('num')`, which returns `null`

Going further, `dd($request->all())` returns:

`array:1 [
  "/cargar-mas-atracciones/1" => null
]`

This is my ajax request:

```
function carga_mas(id){
    event.preventDefault();
    // console.log(id);
      $('.rotar_icono').addClass("rotate");

      $num = $num + 2;
      var route = site_url+'cargar-mas-atracciones/'+id;
      $.ajax({
        url: route,
        data : {num:$num},
        type : 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success : function(response){
          // console.log(response);
          cargar__atracciones(response);
        }
      });
  }
```

Seems like the server is ignoring GET data, any ideas?

Comment: You can simply do `$var = $atracciones->count() > $request->get('num')`.

Comment: what do you get when you `dd($atracciones->count(), $request->get('num')` ?

Comment: @RoboRobok That's right, thanks.

Comment: @usrNotFound "6" and "null". I did some research on it and tried:

`$request->get('num')`, `$request->input('num')` and `$request->num`.

Sadly, it still outputs "null". Any ideas?

Comment: probably look at the form maybe be the field is called something else. I would `dd($request()->all())` and see what I get just to be sure as well

Comment: @usrNotFound Ok, I've updated the question with results